# using CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER for grabbing Json data does not result in empty but also does not print

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

I am working on some code on PHP that allow me to get json data from an api.
so
1 typical URL is not providing the data no matter what. when checking for empty in the $result, it says it has value in it, but when required to print it does not print or echo. This same URL  when tested in PostMan works and provide data.
The strange part is the data are in the same format and
all other URLs calls work fine both on PostMan and through the code below.
I was able to trace to here and I am suspecting something is wrong with the "curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);" or the "curl_exec". the rest I am stuck!
All URL data return are similar and same format in PostMan.

No error returns.

```
    function getRestCall($url, $data = null, $method = self::METHOD_GET)
        {
        
        $curl = curl_init();
        
        
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        
        printf('<h2>URL</h2>' . $url);
        // Set authentication parameters
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $this->username . ':' . $this->password);

        // Don't send as json when attaching files to tasks.

        if (is_string($data) || empty($data['file']))
            {
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                'content-Type: application/json'
            )); // Send as JSON
            }

        // Dont print result

        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
       
        // Set maximum timeout limit

        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $this->timeout);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $this->timeout);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);

        // Don't verify SSL connection

        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

        // Define methods
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);

        if ($method == self::METHOD_POST)
            {
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            }
        elseif ($method == self::METHOD_PUT)
            {
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
            }
        elseif ($method == self::METHOD_DELETE)
            {
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'DELETE');
            }
        
        // Define post data if we have the correct method

        if (!is_null($data) && ($method == self::METHOD_POST || $method == self::METHOD_PUT))
            {
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
            }
        
        
        try
            {
            $return = curl_exec($curl);

            if ($this->debug)
                {
                $info = curl_getinfo($curl);
                echo '<pre>';
                print_r($info);
               
                echo '</pre>';
                if ($info['http_code'] == 0)
                    {
                    echo '<br />error num: ' . curl_errno($curl);
                    echo '<br />error: ' . curl_error($curl);
                    }

                if (!is_null($data))
                    {
                    echo '<br />Sent info:<br /><pre>';
                    print_r($data);
                    echo '</pre>';
                    }
                }
            
            }
        catch(Exception $e)
            {
            $return = null;
            if ($this->debug)
                {
                echo "Exception caught: " . $e->getMessage();
                }
            }

        if ($return === false)
            {
             printf('<h2>Return value is error, SHOW!!:  </h2>'); 
             $return = curl_error($curl);
             //printf('<h2>Return value is not empty, SHOW!!:  </h2>'. $return);
            }else
         {
             printf('<h2>no error</h2>');
         }
        curl_close($curl);
        return $return;
        }
```

I am suspecting something is wrong with the "curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);" or the "curl_exec".

Comment: What is the output from `var_dump($return)` ? OR `print_r($return)` ?

Comment: Have you confirmed that errors are on and appearing ?

Comment: Thanks! it works. somehow I cannot printf and that is the reason!